# Sharing a link on Twitter

Tags: twitter, linker, share

Hey all,
I would like to make possible to share links of my website on twitter with a click. I've already done this for facebook, just one click and the classic facebook window appears where you can also write what you're thinking while sharing the link.

Is it possible to do the same for Twitter? I've searched through the web but I could only find apps that go on your browser and not for a website. Moreover it would be better a simple code instead of an app, if it's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?
[Twitter tweet button](http://twitter.com/goodies/tweetbutton)
[Twitter Dev tweet button](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button)

Comment: That's what I exactly was searching for. Thanks a lot!